# How to disable/remove apple news on podcasts app

Tags: podcasts.app

I want to disable all the subscriptions I've never subscribed to, such as Apple News and Apple Music, on the Podcasts app. Is that possible? It is very annoying because they automatically download on my watch and I have no interest in them.[image]